# Excel - Fill cell background colour x% from left to right

Tags: excel, vba

I wish to fill the background of a cell but only a certain % of it.  For example if the cell needs to be covered by 25% it would be filled 25% of the cell from left to right.  I am aware of the following solution:

https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/45677/how-to-create-progress-bars-in-excel-with-conditional-formatting/

However, the cell I will be using will have text in it and not a numerical value.  Adding a numerical value is not a viable solution.

I current have some VBA that is looping through each cell populating the cell with the relevant text string.  As I loop through the cells the number % required is available.  Any thought on how I can use the conditional formatting idea above but with the VBA number would be appreciated.

If you have any ideas on how I may improve the question that is always welcome.

Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: Put a number in the cell but use a custom format to display text instead?  Might work for a smallish range...

Comment: Sorry, the text is nothing to do with the numerical number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
Sub PartialFill()
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlPatternLinearGradient
        .Gradient.Degree = 0
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Clear
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0).Color = 5296274
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.25).Color = 5296274
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(0.26).Color = 16777215
        .Gradient.ColorStops.Add(1).Color = 16777215
    End With
End Sub
```

Replace Selection with your range
If you want the colorstops value to be a variable it should be declared as string. It won't work as long.